# Pass arguments to external command - stop parsing

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and trying to stop parsing when calling an external cmd. Sample code:

```
$Exe = "C:\Program Files\Test\keygen.exe"
# Execute command with arguments
$Exe --% "-Z"
```

I think `--%` is correct to stop the parser, but this returns the error "The '--' operator only works on numbers. The operand is a 'System.String'.

What is wrong here?

Comment: You forgot to `&`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks. Now working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your command as a string. PowerShell's default behavior is to echo strings and execute bare words:

```
PS C:\> ping.exe 127.0.0.1

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
PS C:\> $exe = 'ping.exe'
PS C:\> $exe
ping.exe
PS C:\> $exe 127.0.0.1
At line:1 char:6
+ $exe 127.0.0.1
+      ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '127.0.0.1' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

You need to use the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators) (`&`) to have PowerShell execute string commands:

```
PS C:\> & $exe 127.0.0.1

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```